# Overriding onmouseover events in Google Chart API's

Tags: google-visualization

I am using the Google PieChart visualization and by default, when you mouse over the various slices of the pie chart, there is a tooltip that displays information about the data slice. I would like to disable this tooltip from displaying altogether.

You can easily add a listener to the onmouseover event, but I'd like to override that event altogether. Has anyone done this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Configuration_Options), you can stop the tooltip from displaying by setting the trigger in your options:

```
var options = {
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'none'
    }
};
```

You can see it in action on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/FN36W/1/). Just a note, the only other valid option is `hover` which is set by default.

Comment: Nice post. I would also like to know, if we want to display something other information (custom info) in the tool tip, is there any way ?

Comment: @gthmgeeky just had another look through the docs and it doesn't look like it, which is a shame as it would be very useful to be able to do that!

Comment: You can certainly do this these days.